# How to do a tile plot of a specialised plotting function from package

Tags: r, layout, plot, tiles, par

I want to plot 4 of the following plots as an `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` type arrangement.

```
install.packages("wavelets")
require(wavelets)
dat <- rnorm(100)
plot.modwt(modwt(dat)) #4 of these in a 2x2 grid is desired
```

However, `layout` and `mfrow` based attempts have not succeeded.

I will be giving the correct answer a bounty.

Comment: The issue with that specific plot is that it has already a call to `layout` embedded, so any attempts will be overwritten. See this snippet of the source code of the function: `... if (plot.X) {
            nf <- layout(matrix(c(2, 2, 1, 1), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE), 
                c(1, 2), c(2, 1), TRUE) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @plannapus commented, the function `plot.modwt` already calls layout. So you will need to alter the original function.

1. If you type `plot.modwt` in you R console, you will get the complete definition.
2. Copy this function and save it as a new function, say, `my.plot.modwt`.
3. Comment out the layout line in this function
4. Set up your new layout. This worked for me:

   ```
   nf = layout(matrix(c(3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 5,8, 6), 4, 2, byrow = TRUE), 
        c(2,2), c(2,1, 2, 1), TRUE)
   layout.show(nf)
   ```
5. Call your function (4 times )to create plots:

   ```
   my.plot.modwt(modwt(dat1))
   my.plot.modwt(modwt(dat2))
   my.plot.modwt(modwt(dat3))
   my.plot.modwt(modwt(dat4))
   ```

Note, some other alterations to the layout will probably be needed.

---

My code:

```
y.plot.modwt = function (x, levels = NULL, draw.boundary = FALSE, type = "stack", 
          col.plot = "black", col.boundary = "red", X.xtick.at = NULL, 
          X.ytick.at = NULL, Stack.xtick.at = NULL, Stack.ytick.at = NULL, 
          X.xlab = "t", y.rlabs = TRUE, plot.X = TRUE, plot.W = TRUE, 
          plot.V = TRUE, ...) 
{
  stackplot.modwt <- function(x, w.range, v.range, col.plot, 
                              col.boundary, draw.boundary, X.xtick.at, X.ytick.at, 
                              Stack.xtick.at, Stack.ytick.at, X.xlab = "t", plot.X = TRUE) {
    innerplot <- function(x, y, type = "l", xtick.at, ytick.at) {
      if (is.null(xtick.at) == FALSE || is.null(ytick.at) == 
            FALSE) {
        plot(x, y, type = "l", axes = FALSE, frame.plot = TRUE)
        <snip>

if (plot.X) {
      #nf <- layout(matrix(c(2, 2, 1, 1), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE), 
      #             c(1, 2), c(2, 1), TRUE)
      par(mai = c(0.6, 0.4, 0.1, 0.6))

<snip>
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Only one plot in the right hand side and it keeps getting overwritten with each successive call to `my.plot.modwt`

Comment: @user2763361 It works for me. I've put down a condensed version of the code.

Comment: I'm not sure why you commented out `layout?` Isn't that what we're supposed to be changing? I was saying that I replaced what you commented out with the line that you suggested but it didn't work.

Comment: @user2763361 I understand. My solution involves calling the function four times.

Comment: I appreciate the time investment you made

Comment: You may need to remind me to bounty you when it's available 2 days